# Erro ao incluir imagem com tag <img .../> por meio de string em PHP

Tags: php, html, string, imagem

Não consigo fazer uma imagem referenciada no código abaixo aparecer. Qual pode ser o problema?

```
<style>

    table{width:  100%;$borda;$fonte;}
    th{text-align: center;}
    td{text-align: center;$tam_etiq}
    tr{ }
    td.col1{text-align: center;}
    td.titulo{font-size: 24px;$tit_neg;$cor_tit;$sizetit;$tit_center;}
    td.desc{color:#$cor_desc;$desc_neg;$sizedesc}

</style>
";

$titulo = $_POST['titulo'];
$descr1 = $_POST['descricao1'];
$descr2 = $_POST['descricao2'];
$descr3 = $_POST['descricao3'];
$quant_linhas = count($titulo);
$imagem = $_FILES["<img src=https://servicosespeciais.com.br/comfica/email/logotipo.png />"];


//echo $quant_linhas;

$html.= "<table>";
$html.="<col style='width: 100%' class='col1'>";
$html.="<col style='width: 100%'>";
$html.="<col style='width: 100%'>";
for ($i = 0; $i < $quant_linhas; $i++) {
    $j++;
    $k++;
    if ($j == 1) {
        $html.= "<tr>";
    }
    $html.="<td>";
    $html.="<table frame='box'>";
    $html.="<col style='width: 100%' class='col1'>";
    $html.="<col style='width: 100%'>";
    $html.="<col style='width: 100%'>";
    $html.="<col style='width: 100%'>";

    $html.="<tr>";
    $html.="";
    $html.="</tr>";
    $html.="<tr>";
    $html.="<td class='titulo'>$imagem</td>";
    $html.="</tr>";

    $html.="<tr>";    
    $html.="<td class='titulo'> ROMANEIO DE TRANSPORTE </td>";
    $html.="</tr>";
    $html.="<tr>";
```

Comment: Rapaz explique melhor, não só poste o código não, fica ruim pra ajudar a entender o seu problema

Comment: Sempre coloque o código completo. Código incompleto nos faz pensar que seu erro pode ser maior ou menor. Ou mesmo evitar que ajudemos apropriadamente. E sempre explique a situação de problema de forma completa e concisa.

Answer (score 2):

### Problema

Olhe esta linha:

```
$imagem = $_FILES["<img src=https://servicosespeciais.com.br/comfica/email/logotipo.png />"];
```

Isso é basicamente **impossível**. Você não tem essa string toda como índice de $_FILES pelo simples fato de ser uma tag HTML de imagem (`<img .../>`).

Agora olhe nesta linha:

```
$html.="<td class='titulo'>$imagem</td>";
```

Você claramente só queria a tag de imagem aqui . Não o valor de `$_FILES['...']` em que o índice é uma tag HTML de imagem.

### Corrigindo o problema

Mude a linha abaixo:

```
$imagem = $_FILES["<img src=https://servicosespeciais.com.br/comfica/email/logotipo.png />"];
```

Por:

```
$imagem = "<img src=https://servicosespeciais.com.br/comfica/email/logotipo.png />";
```

Se a imagem no endereço especificado existir, ela vai aparecer com essa modificação.

### Sugestão de leitura extra

Caso faça, no futuro, *upload* de imagens, dê uma olhada [neste 'artigo'](https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/features.file-upload.post-method.php) do PHP.net.